# Radio buttons not showing up in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, radio-button, components, render

I'm trying to create a very simple radio button system within react but cannot get the radio buttons to render correctly. I have attached my code as well as what the output looks like. What can I do to get the radio buttons to properly show up? Thanks!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DDEf.png

```
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    var user = props.location.state;
    this.state = {
      selected: ''
    };
  }

  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({selected: e.target.value})
  }

    render() {
      return(
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <h1> Welcome! </h1>
      <h4> Are you a: </h4>
      
      <ul>
        <li>
          <label>
            <input
              type="radio"
              value="student"
              checked={value === "student"}
              onChange={this.onChange}
            />
            <h5> Student </h5>
          </label>
        </li>

        <li>
          <label>
            <input
              type="radio"
              value="professor"
              checked={value === "professor"}
              onChange={this.onChange}
            />
            <h5> Professor </h5>
          </label>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
      )
    
  }
}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmU0W.png
```

Comment: Please provide the image of what it looks like here in the question, and not an external link.

Comment: `checked={value === "professor"}` looks weird to me. I don't see `value` defined anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't look to be anything wrong with the markup. I suspect that the styling is preventing the display of the radio buttons. On the image everything is centered - is it possible that the h5 header is rendering over the radio button. If you inspect the source of the web page and see the radio buttons in the DOM that indicates that styling is the issue.

Comment: thank you for your reply. You may be right as it does appear in the console under the h5...